# Alfresco : send mail to all members custom button doesn't work in some specific Sites

Tags: javascript, tinymce, share, alfresco, dashboard

On the "share" part of the application, I've got an issue in a specific site dashboard.
This problem occurs randomly when you create a site and apparently with no particular reason.
My issue is concerning the "Site Profile" dashlet. I've developed a custom button which enables the user to send an e-mail to one or multiple members who have subscribed to the site's informations. It relies on a javascript file name "ts-send-mail-to-all-members.js"
 When you click on it, an pop-up window is open containing checkboxes which enables you to select members, a TinyMCE component, which enables you to write the e-mail and a two buttons, one to send e-mail the other one to close the pop-up.

The subscription button had also been created doesn't generate any error.

The problem occurs when you click on the button which enables you to send e-mails.
There is a javascript error that is throwned accordingly to the site's dashboard configuration.
1) For instance, if the only dashlet present on the page is "Site Profile", I have this following error :

```
Alfresco.module.SimpleDialog is not a constructor
http://localhost:8080/share/res/modules/ts-send-mail-to-all-members.js
Line 139
```

The code line is the following :

```
var sendMailToAllMembersDialog = new Alfresco.module.SimpleDialog(this.id + "-sendMailToAllMembersDialog");
```

2) I didn't target the specific configuration to obtain this error, but randomly you can also have this error :

```
tinyMCE is not defined
[Break on this error] tinyMCE.init({
```

Apparently, tinyMCE is not identified by Alfresco which throws an exception. In the script, "tinyMCE.init" is the first statement where the component is called. I've made researches on this error and usually you just have to add a `<script>` tag with the `src=""` argument in order to specify where tiny_mce.js is located. I can be an URL or its location in the Alfresco application. 
However, my script is entirely write in JavaScript and I can't write HTML statements.

3) You've got a third case in which the pop-up appears and the functionnality works without any exception being throwned. This case occurs when you add the "Events List" dashlet, on the Site's dashboard.

Here is the "ts-send-mail-to-all-members.js" source code :

```
/**
 * Copyright (C) T&S.
 *
 */

/**
 * ts-abonnement-site module
 *
 * 
 *
 * @namespace Alfresco.module
 * @class Alfresco.module.TsAbonnementSite
 */
(function()
{

   var Dom = YAHOO.util.Dom,
      Event = YAHOO.util.Event,
      Element = YAHOO.util.Element,
      Bubbling = YAHOO.Bubbling,
      KeyListener = YAHOO.util.KeyListener
      nodeRef = "";

   /**
    * CreateSite constructor.
    *
    * @param htmlId {string} A unique id for this component
    * @return {Alfresco.CreateSite} The new DocumentList instance
    * @constructor
    */
   Alfresco.module.TsSendMailToAllMembers = function(containerId)
   {
      var instance = Alfresco.util.ComponentManager.get(this.id);
      if (instance !== null)
      {
         throw new Error("An instance of Alfresco.module.TsSendMailToAllMembers already exists.");
      }

      Alfresco.module.TsSendMailToAllMembers.superclass.constructor.call(this, "Alfresco.module.TsSendMailToAllMembers", containerId, ["button", "container", "connection", "selector", "json"]);

      return this;
   };

   YAHOO.extend(Alfresco.module.TsSendMailToAllMembers, Alfresco.component.Base,
   {
       members:[],

       options:{
           siteId:""
       },

       onReady: function TS_onReady()
       {
           this.widgets.sendMailToAllMembersButton = Alfresco.util.createYUIButton(this, "btn-sendMailToAllMembers", this.showSendMailForm);
           this.widgets.sendMailToAllMembersButton.set("className", "mailBtn mailToAllMembersBtn");
           Bubbling.on('selectDeselectAllChanged', this.selectDeselectAllChanged);
           Bubbling.on('selectDeselectMemberChanged', this.selectDeselectMemberChanged);
       },

       showSendMailForm: function()
       {
        // Intercept before dialog show
            var doBeforeDialogShow = function TsSendMailToAllMembers_doBeforeDialogShow(
                    p_form, p_dialog) {
                Alfresco.util.populateHTML(
                        [p_dialog.id + "-dialogTitle", this.msg("label.sendMailToAllMembersForm.title") ], 
                        [p_dialog.id + "-dialogHeader", this.msg("label.sendMailToAllMembersForm.header") ],
                        [p_dialog.id + "-members-label", this.msg("label.sendMailToAllMembersForm.members") ],
                        [p_dialog.id + "-subject-label", this.msg("label.sendMailToAllMembersForm.subject") ],
                        [p_dialog.id + "-body-label", this.msg("label.sendMailToAllMembersForm.body") ],
                        [p_dialog.id + "-ok-label", this.msg("label.sendMailToAllMembersForm.btn.send.mail") ],
                        [p_dialog.id + "-cancel-label", this.msg("label.sendMailToAllMembersForm.btn.cancel") ]);

                p_dialog.dialog.header.innerHTML = this.msg("label.sendMailToAllMembersForm.dialog.title");

                Dom.get(p_dialog.id + "-shortName").value = this.options.siteId;

                tinyMCE.init({
                    mode : "exact",
                    elements: p_dialog.id + "-body",
                    convert_fonts_to_spans: false,
                    theme: 'advanced',
                    width: "100%",
                    theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,|,bullist,numlist,|,forecolor,|,undo,redo,removeformat",
                    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
                    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
                    theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
                    theme_advanced_resizing: false,
                    theme_advanced_buttons2: null,
                    theme_advanced_buttons3: null,
                    theme_advanced_path: false,
                    language: 'fr'
                });

                Alfresco.util.Ajax.request(
                {
                   url: Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + "api/sites/" + this.options.siteId + "/memberships",
                   dataObj:
                   {
                       htmlid : p_dialog.id + "-membersContainer"
                   },
                   successCallback:
                   {
                      fn: this.onMembersLoaded,
                      scope: this
                   }
                });
            };

            var doBeforeFormSubmit = function ()
            {
                Dom.get(this.id + "-sendMailToAllMembersDialog-mailbody").value = tinyMCE.get(this.id + "-sendMailToAllMembersDialog-body").getContent({format : 'raw'});

                var membersIds = "";
                var cbs = YAHOO.util.Selector.query("input[id^='cb_']");

                for (var i=0; i<cbs.length; i++)
                {
                    var cb = cbs[i];
                    if (cb.checked)
                    {
                        var id = cb.id.replace("cb_", "");
                        if(cbs.length == 1 || i == cbs.length - 1) {
                            membersIds += id;
                        } else {
                            membersIds += id + ",";
                        }
                    }
                }

                Dom.get(this.id + "-sendMailToAllMembersDialog-membersIds").value = membersIds;

                this.widgets.dialog.widgets.okButton.set("disabled", true);
                this.widgets.dialog.widgets.cancelButton.set("disabled", true);
            };

            // Using Forms Service, so always create new
            // instance
            var sendMailToAllMembersDialog = new Alfresco.module.SimpleDialog(this.id + "-sendMailToAllMembersDialog");

            this.widgets.dialog = sendMailToAllMembersDialog;

            sendMailToAllMembersDialog.setOptions(
            {
                width : "60em",
                templateUrl : Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + "ts/sendMailToAllMembers",
                actionUrl : Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + "ts/sendHtmlMail",
                destroyOnHide : true,
                doBeforeFormSubmit:{
                    fn:doBeforeFormSubmit,
                    scope: this
                },
                doBeforeDialogShow : {
                    fn : doBeforeDialogShow,
                    scope : this
                },
                onSuccess : {
                    fn : function TsSendMailToAllMembers_success(response) {
                        YAHOO.Bubbling.fire(
                            "sendMailToAllMembersForm_success",
                            {
                                nodeRef : response.json.persistedObject
                            });

                        Alfresco.util.PopupManager.displayMessage({
                            text : this.msg("message.sendMailToAllMembersForm.success")
                        });
                    },
                    scope : this
                },
                onFailure : {
                    fn : function TsSendMailToAllMembers_failure(response) {
                        Alfresco.util.PopupManager.displayMessage({
                            text : this.msg("message.sendMailToAllMembersForm.failure")
                        });
                    },
                    scope : this
                }
            }).show();
       },

       onMembersLoaded: function TS_onMembersLoaded(response)
       {
           this.members = response.json;
           this.updateMembersList(response.config.dataObj.htmlid);
       },

       updateMembersList : function TS_updateMembersList(containerId)
       {
           var div = Dom.get(containerId);
           div.innerHTML = "<div class=\"memberDiv\">" +
               "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"selectDeselectAllCb\" checked=\"true\" onclick=\"YAHOO.Bubbling.fire('selectDeselectAllChanged')\" class=\"memberCb\"/>" +
               "<label for=\"selectDeselectAllCb\" class=\"memberLabel\">" + 
               this.msg('label.selectDeselectAll') + "</label>" +
               "</div>";

           for (var i=0; i<this.members.length; i++)
           {
               var member = this.members[i];
               var avatar = Alfresco.constants.URL_CONTEXT + "/components/images/no-user-photo-64.png";

               if (member.authority.avatar && member.avatar != "")
               {
//                 exemple:
//                 api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/697ec77c-b881-4c16-82b6-4f80fea1514b/content/thumbnails/avatar
                   avatar = Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + member.authority.avatar + "?c=force";
               }
               div.innerHTML += "<div class=\"memberDiv\">" +
//                  "<img class=\"memberAvatar\" src=\"" + avatar + "\"/>" +
                    "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"cb_" + member.authority.userName + "\" checked=\"true\" onclick=\"YAHOO.Bubbling.fire('selectDeselectMemberChanged')\" class=\"memberCb\"/>" +
                    "<label for=\"cb_" + member.authority.userName + "\" class=\"memberLabel\">" + 
                            member.authority.firstName + " " + member.authority.lastName + "</label>" +
                    "</div>";
           }
       },

       selectDeselectAllChanged: function selectDeselectAllChanged(){
           var selectDeselectAllCb = Dom.get('selectDeselectAllCb');
           var checked = selectDeselectAllCb.checked;
           var cbs = YAHOO.util.Selector.query("input[id^='cb_']");

           for (var i=0, j=cbs.length; i<j; i++)
           {
               var cb = cbs[i];
               cb.checked = checked;
           }
       },

       selectDeselectMemberChanged: function selectDeselectMemberChanged(){
           var selectDeselectAllCb = Dom.get('selectDeselectAllCb');
           var cbs = YAHOO.util.Selector.query("input[id^='cb_']");
           var firstChecked = false;
           if (cbs[0] != null){
               firstChecked = cbs[0].checked;
           }

           for (var i=0, j=cbs.length; i<j; i++)
           {
               var cb = cbs[i];
               if (cb.checked === firstChecked){
                   continue;
               }
               else{
                   selectDeselectAllCb.checked = false;
                   return;
               }
           }

           selectDeselectAllCb.checked = firstChecked;
       },

       /**
        * Set messages for this component.
        *
        * @method setMessages
        * @param obj {object} Object literal specifying a set of messages
        * @return {Alfresco.SampleComponent} returns 'this' for method chaining
        */
       setMessages: function SampleComponent_setMessages(obj)
       {
           Alfresco.util.addMessages(obj, this.name);
           return this;
       }

   });
})();

Alfresco.module.geTsSendMailToAllMembersInstance = function()
{
   var instanceId = "alfresco-TsSendMailToAllMembers-instance";
   return Alfresco.util.ComponentManager.get(instanceId) || new Alfresco.module.TsSendMailToAllMembers(instanceId);
};
```

Here is the "site-profile.get.head.ftl" source code :

```
    <#include "../component.head.inc">
    <@link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${page.url.context}/res/modules/ts/ts.css" />
    <@script type="text/javascript" src="${page.url.context}/res/modules/ts-abonnement-site.js"></@script>
    <@script type="text/javascript" src="${page.url.context}/res/modules/ts-send-mail-to-all-members.js"></@script>
```

Here is the "site-profile.get.html.ftl" source code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
   new Alfresco.module.TsAbonnementSite("${args.htmlid}").setOptions(
   {
        siteId: "${profile.shortName}"
   }).setMessages(${messages});

   new Alfresco.module.TsSendMailToAllMembers("${args.htmlid}").setOptions(
   {
        siteId: "${profile.shortName}"
   }).setMessages(${messages});
//]]></script>

<div id="${args.htmlid}-sendMailToAllMembersDialog"></div>

<div class="dashlet site-profile">
   <div class="title">${msg("header.siteProfile")}</div>
   <div class="body">
      <div class="msg">
         <#if profile.iconurl?exists && profile.iconurl != "">
            <img src="/share/proxy/alfresco/api/node/${profile.iconurl}/content/thumbnails/avatar?c=force" height="60px" style="float:left;margin: 5px;"/>
         </#if>
         <h3><#if (profile.title != "")>${msg("text.welcome", profile.title)?html}<#else>${msg("text.welcome", profile.shortName)?html}</#if></h3>
<#if (profile.description != "")>
         <p>${profile.description?html}</p>
</#if>
<#if profile.customProperties??>
   <#list profile.customProperties?keys as prop>
      <#assign customValue=profile.customProperties[prop].value>    
      <#if customValue?starts_with('alfresco-php://') == true>
         <p><a href="${url.context}/proxy/alfresco-php/${customValue?substring(15)?html}" target="_blank" class="theme-color-1">${profile.customProperties[prop].title?html}</a></p>
      <#else>
         <p>
            <span class="label">${profile.customProperties[prop].title?html}</span>
            <span>${customValue?html}</span>
         </p>
       </#if>
   </#list>
</#if>
<#if (sitemanagers?exists && sitemanagers?size &gt; 0)>
         <p>
            <span class="label">${msg("label.siteAdmin")}</span>
   <#list sitemanagers as sitemanager>
      <#if sitemanager.authority.authorityType = 'USER'>
            <a href="${url.context}/page/user/${sitemanager.authority.userName?url}/profile" class="theme-color-1">${sitemanager.authority.firstName?html}<#if sitemanager.authority.lastName != ""> ${sitemanager.authority.lastName?html}</#if></a><#if sitemanager_has_next>,</#if>
      <#else>
            <span>${sitemanager.authority.displayName?html}</span><#if sitemanager_has_next>,</#if>
      </#if>
   </#list>
         </p>
</#if>
         <p><span class="label">${msg("label.type")}</span>&nbsp;${msg("text." + profile.type?lower_case)}</p>
         <p><span class="label">${msg("label.visibility")}</span>&nbsp;${msg("text." + (profile.visibility!"unknown")?lower_case)}</p>
         <p><span class="label">${msg("ts-site-profile.siteMembersNbr")}</span>&nbsp;${profile.siteMembersNbr?html}</p>
         <p><span class="label">${msg("ts-site-profile.creationDate")}</span>&nbsp;${profile.creationDate}</p>
         <p>
            <button id="${args.htmlid}-btn-sendMailToAllMembers" title='${msg("ts-site-profile.sendMailToAllMembers")}'>
                    <img class="mailBtn" src="${url.context}/res/modules/ts/images/email-icon.png"/></button>
            <div id="${args.htmlid}-div-btn-abo" style="display:none;">
                <button id="${args.htmlid}-btn-subscribeDaily" title='${msg("ts-site-profile.subscribeDaily")}'>
                    <img class="mailBtn" src="${url.context}/res/modules/ts/images/calendar-selection-day-icon.png"/></button>
                <button id="${args.htmlid}-btn-subscribeWeekly" title='${msg("ts-site-profile.subscribeWeekly")}'>
                    <img class="mailBtn" src="${url.context}/res/modules/ts/images/calendar-selection-week-icon.png"/></button>
            </div>
            <div id="${args.htmlid}-div-btn-delete" style="display:none;">
                <button id="${args.htmlid}-btn-delete">
                    <img class="mailBtn" src="" id="${args.htmlid}-img-btn-delete"/></button>
            </div>
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So, if you have any specific idea...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution.
All I've had to do is add those lines in `"site-profile.get.head.ftl"` :

```
<#include "../component.head.inc">

<script type="text/javascript" src="${page.url.context}/res/modules/editors/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<@script type="text/javascript" src="${page.url.context}/res/modules/editors/tiny_mce.js"></@script>
<@script type="text/javascript" src="${page.url.context}/res/components/form/rich-text.js"></@script>
<@link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${page.url.context}/res/modules/ts/ts.css" />
<@script type="text/javascript" src="${page.url.context}/res/modules/ts-abonnement-site.js"></@script>
<@script type="text/javascript" src="${page.url.context}/res/modules/ts-send-mail-to-all-members.js"></@script>

<!-- Simple Dialog -->
<@script type="text/javascript" src="${page.url.context}/res/modules/simple-dialog.js"></@script>
```

Some of those lines were in the "List events" dashlet "head.ftl" file. 
Now, the dashlet doesn't need to be included to work and there is no conflict.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't really need to incluse tinyMCE again, because it's mostly already done.

take a look at the template file alfresco-template.ftl here you'll see the following;

```
<#macro templateHtmlEditorAssets>
<!-- HTML Editor Assets -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${page.url.context}/res/modules/editors/tiny_mce/tiny_mce${DEBUG?string("_src", "")}.js"></script>
    <@script type="text/javascript" src="${page.url.context}/res/modules/editors/tiny_mce.js"></@script>
    <@script type="text/javascript" src="${page.url.context}/res/modules/editors/yui_editor.js"></@script>
</#macro>
```

So this could be a clash that it already sees it as an html field and imports tinyMCE double.

Can you check this?

If it's already loaded, then you only need to enable the field correctly.

Second, you need to have a head.html.ftl where you can include specific library files.

Take a look at sample dashlets how they're build.

Comment: I've check and those <script> tags exists. I don't think there is any double declaration of tinyMCE. There is also this line <@script type="text/javascript" src="${page.url.context}/res/modules/simple-dialog.js"></@script> in several .head.ftl files. What is strange is that this problem just appears in a specific site and the others don't throw any exception.

Comment: Maybe I've forgot to a say this, but when the "Alfresco.module.SimpleDialog is not a constructor error occurs", the tinyMCE one dissapears.

Comment: Apparently, the functionnality doesn't work on any Site, if you remove the "List events" dashlet.

Comment: Can you provide the full Dashlet code, at least the JS and FTL

Comment: I've added the source code of the .js file, the "get.head.ftl" file and the "get.html.ftl", in the first post which contains my question.

Comment: Ok, so now, I only have the TinyMCE is not defined error that occurs. All I've done is add this line :
<!-- Simple Dialog -->
<@script type="text/javascript" src="${page.url.context}/res/modules/simple-dialog.js"></@script>
In the "site-profile.get.head.ftl" file.
I've added in the same file those lines :
<@script type="text/javascript" src="${page.url.context}/res/modules/editors/tiny_mce.js"></@script>
    <@script type="text/javascript" src="${page.url.context}/res/modules/editors/yui_editor.js"></@script>

But it doesn't solve the TinyMCE error.

Comment: I also see an import at the file: <script type="text/javascript" src="${page.url.context}/res/modules/editors/tiny_mce/tiny_mce${DEBUG?string("_src", "")}.js"></script>, so you've got 2 js files you need to import according to the alfresco-template.ftl

Comment: Even when looking in the source when an TinyMCE field is triggered I see both js files